# Refering to a jsf input from javaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsf

I got a google map with an infoWindow, my info window looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         position: latLng,
         content: '<input type="text" /><input type="submit" />'
    }).open(map);
</script>
```

Alright, so this makes a nice little infoWindow with one text input and a submit button.

When i press the button i want the input from the text input to be submitted into my jsf code

```
<h:inputText id="someInput" value="#{test.someInput}" />
```

test.someInput should get the value of the text input from the javascript.

Since it's inside a infoWindow I don't think i can just do:

```
new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     position: latLng,
     content: '<h:inputText id="someInput" value="#{test.someInput}" />'
}).open(map);
```

No matter what i do it doesn't seem to work atleast.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hm, i think i just found a workaround.
By doing: 

    var infoWindowContent = document.getElementById('content');
    new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        position: latLng,
        content: infoWindowContent
    }).open(map);

and :

    <div id="content">    
    <h:inputText id="someInput" value="#{test.someInput}" />
    </div>
this did actually work :)

Comment: Do you understand that JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator? When writing JavaScript, you should not be looking at JSF source code, but at its generated HTML output (rightclick, *View Source* in browser). There surely isn't a `<h:inputText id="someInput">` in the generated HTML output. Instead, there is likely a `<input type="text" id="someForm:someInput">` in the HTML output. This is also exactly what JavaScript is seeing and has to deal with (you know, JS runs in the client side).